# How to use regex to exclude a url path?

Tags: regex

I'm working on a process where I have to exclude a specific url path.

```
--exclude "/faq"
```

The above will exclude example.com/faq but not the other paths such as example.com/questions, example.com/needed, example.com/answers ....

What I want is:-

example.com/cricket-or-football/question-3695225 --> only this
(instead of)
example.com/cricket-or-football/question-3695225/3699293/3463987 -----> has to be excluded.

How can I do this in regular expression?

I tried:-

```
--exclude "/.+/question-[0-9]/.+"
```

But its not working!

Comment: Which command?  Some implement --exclude differently.

Comment: Its a Ruby script:- https://github.com/hartator/wayback-machine-downloader

Comment: Try `--exclude "/[\/]+\/question-[0-9]+\/.+/"`

Comment: If it's a Ruby script, add the ruby tag.

Comment: no tag is needed before, it just works to exclude paths like   --exclude "/faq"

Comment: Maybe the question should be, "What is a Ruby regex that would exclude a URL path?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any `/` will need to be escaped.  Therefore `--exclude "/faq"` should be `--exclude "\/faq"`

Your other example:

```
--exclude "^/.+/question-[0-9]/.+"
```

should be:

```
--exclude "^\/.+\/question-[0-9]\/"
```